# how to add elements row wise in a DataFrame with a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have two dictionaries, one contains the generators list and the other contains their values.

```
dic1 = {
    'coal': ['genCoal1', 'genCoal2', 'genCoal3'],
    'gas': ['genGas1', 'genGas2', 'genGas3']
}
dic2 = {
    'genCoal1': [12,23,34],
    'genCoal2': [14,3,34],
    'genCoal3': [16,24,34],
    'genGas1': [132,23,34],
    'genGas2': [13,257,34],
    'genGas3': [92,53,74],
}
```

I converted the second dictionary `dic2` into a pandas DataFrame so it looks like this:

```
     genCoal1  genCoal2  genCoal3  genGas1  genGas2  genGas3
0        12        14        16      132       13       92
1        23         3        24       23      257       53
2        34        34        34       34       34       74
```

what I want to do is I want to add all the coal and gas generators values row wises, so the expected output should look like this:

```
    coal  gas
0    42  237
1    50  333
2   102  142
```

my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
dic1 = {
    'coal': ['genCoal1', 'genCoal2', 'genCoal3'],
    'gas': ['genGas1', 'genGas2', 'genGas3']
}
dic2 = {
    'genCoal1': [12,23,34],
    'genCoal2': [14,3,34],
    'genCoal3': [16,24,34],
    'genGas1': [132,23,34],
    'genGas2': [13,257,34],
    'genGas3': [92,53,74],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic2)
fuelWise = {}
for i in dic1.keys():
    for j in dic1[i]:
        fuelWise[i] = df[j].sum(axis=1)

print(fuelWise)
```

But I am getting this error

```
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the desired columns by specifying the list of column names inside the `[]` brackets like so:

```
coal = df[dic1['coal']].sum(axis=1)
gas = df[dic1['gas']].sum(axis=1)
```

Then you can combine the two outputs into one dataframe:

```
sol = pd.concat([coal, gas], axis=1)
```

finally we will change the names of the columns:

```
sol.columns = dic1.keys()
```

output:

```
print(sol)
>>>    coal  gas
>>> 0    42  237
>>> 1    50  333
>>> 2   102  142
```

Comment: yeah, this is the actual solution that I was looking for, thanks man. I was using unnecessary 2 for loops and also the way I was calling the data was wrong df[j].sum(axis=1).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
coal = df.filter(regex=r".*Coal").sum(axis=1)
gas = df.filter(regex=r".*Gas").sum(axis=1)
print(pd.concat({"coal": coal, "gas": gas}, axis=1))
```

Prints:

```
   coal  gas
0    42  237
1    50  333
2   102  142
```

Comment: ah sorry but it won't work for me becoz in actual there are multiple types of generators (coal, gas, nuclear, hydro etc) and they all are in dic1 and you are not using the dic1 for this